# webstorm 8: less support, Is there a way to globally define less libraries per project?

Tags: less, webstorm

I have main less file where i have all the imports defined, and which is compiled into css. But when i work in partials, errors and warnings are very convenient but it is kind of inconvenient to redefine imports of libs and variables for every partial while i work in them. Is there a way to globally define less libraries per project?

May be I can at least disable errors and warnings for less files then?

Answer (score 5):

Variables/mixins defined in partials are suggested by completion/resolved in other partials; they are just shown underlined as 'not explicitly imported (referenced by name only)', but still available. If you don't like to see the warnings related to variables that aren't explicitly imported, turn 'Resolved by name only' inspection (Settings/Inspections/LESS) off for your project